# Dynamic page transitions in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dynamic

As part of a new project, I have to dynamically create jQuery Mobile pages that are navigated between. So I need to be able to create a page, navigate to it, then delete the previous page. These pages are created from JSON provided by a server. My intention is to avoid using any static markup for these pages and create them entirely dynamically.

Unfortunately, it seems the transitions no longer work- the only one I can get working with this method is fade. The funny thing is, it seems that I'm not the only one with this problem. jQuery Mobile have a [demo page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0-rc.2/docs/pages/dynamic-samples/sample-reuse-page.html) that has the same issue. They're not setting the transition property, so it should default to slide, but it's fading, just like mine.

Looking the problem up has not helped. Others seem to have the problem, but no solution. Is this a known issue with jQuery Mobile, and what causes it? Do I have to use static pages?

Comment: Are you doing it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/e4orL2c2/

Comment: Not quite. The first page is dynamically created as well. I'm trying to create a fiddle to demonstrate, but it's not working yet. What's with the downvote?

Comment: I've got a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PointlessSpike/hxsmaup2/6/. Unfortunately it's not even getting to that bug as for some reason it's not firing the changePage function after the second page change, but that's the general gist of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made your original fiddle work by using **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to bind the dynamic button:

```
var pageName = "default";

$(document).ready(function () {
    function changePage() {
        var newName = pageName == "alpha" ? "beta" : "alpha";

        $("body").append("<div id=\"" + newName + "\" data-role=\"page\"><a id=\"dynamicButton\" data-role=\"button\">" + pageName + "</a></div>");

        $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#" + newName, {
            transition: "slide"
        });
        $("#" + pageName).remove();
        pageName = newName;
    };

    changePage();

    $(document).on("click", "#dynamicButton", function () {
        changePage();
    });
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hxsmaup2/8/)**

Comment: I think I understand what happened. It's really weird. I think the id of the buttons being the same caused the binding to persist and caused an issue when the binding happened the next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that this only seems to happen when I keep the id's of the pages I'm creating the same. This was because I would destroy the previous page after the next is switched to. My solution is not to do that; to keep the pages alive, and destroy them the next time a switch happens by storing them in an array, checking if there's more than two, and destroying the first. Thus you only ever have two pages stored, which is good enough.

Still, I'll keep this question alive in case anyone has a better solution.